# My table is not centered

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am new to latex. I have been trying to adjust my table several times to be [1]][1]centered on a landscape page, but my attempts did not work out. I would appreciate your help!

1. Also, if you could illustrate what is this command line for `def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}`
2. And when I searched for similar issues, I read about this resizebox or `\usepackage[strict]{changepage}`? Could they be used here? I am not sure about the latter.
3. How to justify the table notes or improve their outlook?
   P.s. this table is about two pages long.Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{float}   
\usepackage{amsmath }
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand{\etal}{\textit{et al.}}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\centering
{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}

\begin{landscape}
\pagestyle{empty}
\centering\caption{Table 1).}

\centering\begin{longtable}{l*{6}{1}}
\toprule
\hline
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}\\
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Pooled probit}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{RE-probit}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{IV probit‘unweighted‘}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{IV probit}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{4 (2SLS)}}\\
    \midrule

\hline        
        Simulated monthly benefit & -0.0166*** & -0.0177*** & -0.0154* & -0.0318 & -0.00794\\ 
       
        p (v1, v2) & & & -.053^3 & -.049^1 \\ 
        Wald test of exogeneity & & & 3.16^4 & 0.71^2 &  \\ 
        \hline\hline
\multicolumn{5}{p{\linewidth}}{{Pooled regression results (2018-2017) using SOEP v.36 based on the GETTSIM. T statistics in parentheses. All models show the MEs for the household heads at sample means and are weighted except Model 3'. Weighted values apply the SOEP cross-sectional sample weights. Model 1 uses robust standard errors. Producing the 2sls model, a partial out option is used. R2 for the 2SLS Model (0.243) and observations number is fixed for all models (N= 5400). Note that R2 is after partialling-out seven regressors, and the marginal effects dy/dx for factor levels is the discrete change from the base level. ρ (v1, v2) refers to the correlation between the error terms of the first and second stage equations. $^{1} std.err. =.058 $^{.2} \(Prob<chi2\) = 0.3998. $^{3}std.err. = .0296. $^{4} \(Prob<chi2\)= 0.0756.* \(p<0.05\), ** \(p<0.01\), *** \(p<0.001\)} \\
    \end{longtable}
   \end{landscape}   
    }
\end{center}  
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Thank you!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPe16.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBcDG.png

Comment: Please make sure your code actually compiles without errors. The code here is a huge mess. For example there is a `\end{center}` but no `\begin{center}`, and `\caption` has to go inside `longtable`? Please don't just ignore compilation errors.

Comment: What's with `\begin{longtable}{l*{6}{1}}`? Should it be `\begin{longtable}{l*{6}{l}}`?

Comment: \caption and longtable are self-centering, so \centering is neither needed nor beneficial.

Comment: OTOH, your top and bottom page margins appear odd.  I wonder what typearea does?

Comment: Thank you all! @daleif yes, you are right. I had \begin{center} in the beginning but it was removed by mistake after I tried changing the code several times.  Thanks also for the caption remark.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Ok, so I will remove these (the centering commands) then. I did not use further commands other than the ones listed here. I tried using the geometry package earlier but it distorted my other tables. Besides, it is likely that I commit mistakes with where some commands should be exactly positioned.

Comment: Dear @Mico Thanks a million!!! That was of tremendous help, and your additional comments in the code, I learned much from them. Much appreciated, indeed! Is there a reason why when I compiled it to my big table and not just to the minial example table, the stars ** appear next to the digits rather than as superscripts?

Comment: @she - Did you enclose the asterisks in `\sym{...}` wrappers in your "big" table (of which I have no knowledge)?

Comment: @Mico Thanks for your help! I enclosed it in the same position as what you did for the small table (right before \end{longtable}). I paid attention now that the asterisks appear properly (as superscripts) only for the first variable as below (i.e. simulated benefit) while they appear next to the digits for all other variables.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the `\begin{center}`, `\end{center}`, and all three [3!] instances of `\centering` and applying quite a few more code fixes, I ended up with the following result. Is that what you are looking to achieve?

Incidentally, I could not figure out why you're using `longtable` instead of a standard `table`/`tabular` combination.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{float}   
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Prob}{Prob}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
%%%\usepackage{lscape} % don't load both lscape and pdflscape
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\newcommand{\etal}{\textit{et~al.}}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
%%\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage{calc}    % http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
%%\usepackage{amsfonts}  % 'amsfonts' is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}

\usepackage{hyperref} % it's a good idea to load this package _last_

\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}
\pagestyle{empty}

% automatic math mode for columns 2 thru 6:
\begin{longtable}{@{} l *{5}{>{$}c<{$}} @{}}
\caption{Pooled regressions} \\
\toprule
   &\mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{($3'$)} & \mc{(4)} \\
   &\mc{\textbf{Pooled probit}}
   &\mc{\textbf{RE-probit}}
   &\mc{\textbf{IV probit `unweighted'}}
   &\mc{\textbf{IV probit}}
   &\mc{\textbf{4 (2SLS)}}\\
\midrule   
Simulated monthly benefit & -0.0166\sym{***} & -0.0177\sym{***} & -0.0154\sym{*} & -0.0318 & -0.00794\\ 
$\rho (v1, v2)$ & & & -.053\sym{3} & -.049\sym{1} \\ 
Wald test of exogeneity & & & 3.16\sym{4} & 0.71\sym{2} &  \\ 
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{6}{@{} p{\linewidth} @{}}{\small%
Pooled regression results (2018--2017) using SOEP v.36 based on the GETTSIM. $t$-statistics in parentheses. All models show the MEs for the household heads at sample means and are weighted except Model $3'$. Weighted values apply the SOEP cross-sectional sample weights. Model 1 uses robust standard errors. Producing the 2SLS model, a partial out option is used. R\textsuperscript{2} for the 2SLS Model (0.243) and observations number is fixed for all models ($N= 5400$). Note that R\textsuperscript{2} is after partialling-out seven regressors, and the marginal effects $dy/dx$ for factor levels is the discrete change from the base level. 

\smallskip
$\rho (v1, v2)$ refers to the correlation between the error terms of the first and second stage equations. 

\smallskip
\sym{1} std.err.\ = 0.058,
\sym{2} \(\Prob<\chi^2 = 0.3998\), 
\sym{3} std.err.\ = 0.0296,
\sym{4} \(\Prob<\chi^2= 0.0756\). 

\smallskip
\sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\).
} % end of '\multicolumn{6}{..}{...}` directive
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}   
  
\end{document}
```